# How can I store a template literal to be evaluated later with arbitrary parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, template-literals

I have a scenario where I have to interpolate a variable into different templates based on status variable.

```
const output = () => {
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
    else if (status === 'failed') return `${name} matches`;
    else if (status === 'passed') return `${name} does not match`;
    else if (status === 'cancelled') return `${name} cancelled`;
}
```

So instead of so many else if statements I thought of doing it like so:

```
enum Status {
    CANCELLED = 'cancelled',
    FAILED = 'failed',
    PASSED = 'passed',
}

const titleByStatus = {
    [Status.CANCELLED]: `${name} cancelled`,
    [Status.PASSED]: `${name} matches`,
    [Status.FAILED]: `${name} does not match`,
};
  

const output = () => {
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return titleByStatus[status];
    }
}
```

But the question is how do I pass the name variable as argument as it changes.  Or is there some other nicer way to do this?

Comment: just take a function and hand over the name.